# Capture what is in a rectangle of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

This might sound obvious to some of you but I was trying to figure out how to capture only what is in a rectangle.

The below code, uses dlib face detection and draws a bounding box around a detected face.

```
cv2.rectangle(img,(det.left(), det.top()), (det.right(), det.bottom()), color_green, line_width)
```

What I am struggling with is how to capture/ view only what is within the rectangle.

So in this example I only want to see what is in `(det.left(), det.top()), (det.right(), det.bottom())`

```
import sys
import dlib
import cv2

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
color_green = (0,255,0)
line_width = 3
while True:
    ret_val, img = cam.read()
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    dets = detector(rgb_image)
    for det in dets:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(det.left(), det.top()), (det.right(), det.bottom()), color_green, line_width)
    cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break  # esc to quit
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: just take the numpy tutorial. learn about slicing. take the tutorials on docs.opencv.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to implement cropping with numpy slicing.

For a rectangle drawn by:

```
    cv2.rectangle(img,(left,top), (right,bottom), color_green, line_width)
```

You can try cropping as:

```
    new_img = img[top:bottom,left:right,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

to show only the parts that are within the detected boxes you'd want to either black out what's outside the dets (which I find almost impossible) or you could simply draw the desired parts on a black canvas instead

this is why I start here with a black canvas

```py
import sys
import dlib
import cv2
import numpy as np  

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
color_green = (0, 255, 0)
line_width = 3

while True:
    ret_val, img = cam.read()
    # get image dims to creat a black canvas of the same size
    # img shape is (rows, cols, c) or (h, w, c)
    img_h, img_w , _ = img.shape # c = 3 assuming it's a color iamge
    # this will act as our black background / canvas  
    black_tmp = np.zeros((img_h, img_w, 3), dtype=int)
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    dets = detector(rgb_image)
    for det in dets:
        # det cy -> left , top |  x2y2 -> right bottom
        x , y, x2,y2 =  det.left(), det.top(), det.right(), det.bottom()
        # copy the pixels in the desired area to your black background 
        black_tmp [y:y2, x:x2, ::] = img[y:y2, x:x2, ::]
        # maybe draw the rectangle on the new image too 
        cv2.rectangle(black_tmp,(det.left(), det.top()), (det.right(), det.bottom()), color_green, line_width)
    cv2.imshow('my webcam', black_tmp)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break  # esc to quit
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried to only minimally edit your code

here's the np.zeros [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) in case you need it

I hope this helps, if I missed any detail you need please feel free to point it out